# How to drop columns from multiple dataframes at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use a for loop to remove column from multiple dataframes, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm using Colab.

```
train = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')
datasets = [train, test]

for dataset in datasets:
  dataset = dataset.drop('PassengerId', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dataset.drop('PassengerID', axis=1, inplace=True)` instead of `dataset = dataset.drop()`, because in your case you assign the result to the local variable which will be lost.

Comment: @DawnShin could you give some more details? I just checked on pandas 1.3.0 and it worked for me